# Yaml Date Converter

Tags: date, yaml

I am looking for a way to transform the code below into a working function that allows you to take a date as an input and transform it into a written-out date.

:wd(01/01/2024) → would turn into Monday, January 1st, 2024

Currently, I am using a regex match to get the input however I am struggling to assign the variable to a working date. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

- regex: ":wd\((?P.*)\)"

replace: "{{inputDate}}"

vars:

- name: inputDate

type: date

format: "%b, %d, %Y"

Comment: YAML is not a programming language and doesn't do regex or anything like this. Are you using a preprocessor? If so, which one?